# Finding a random variable

Tags: random-variables, weak-convergence

Let $X_{1}, X_{2}, \dots$ be i.i.d Uniform[0,1] random variables.
Find a random variable $X$ such that:

### $$(X_{1}\times\cdots\times X_{n})^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}e^{\sqrt{n}} \overset{d}{\to} X$$

The hint given is to take logs, so here is what I've tried:

$$\log{\left((X_{1}\times\cdots\times X_{n})^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}e^{\sqrt{n}}\right)} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum\log\left(X_i\right) + \sqrt{n} =: Y_{n}$$

Then I tried to find the CDF of $Y_{n}$:

\begin{align*}\mathbb{P}(Y_n \leq x) &= \mathbb{P}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum\log\left(X_i\right) + \sqrt{n} \leq x\right)\\
&=\mathbb{P}\left(\sum\log\left(X_i\right) + n \leq x\sqrt{n}\right)\\
&=\mathbb{P}\left(\sum\log\left(X_1\right) \leq x\sqrt{n} - n\right) \tag{due to i.i.d}\\
&=\mathbb{P}\left(\log\left(X_1\right) \leq \frac{x\sqrt{n}}{n} - 1\right)\\
&=\mathbb{P}\left(X_1 \leq e^{\tfrac{x\sqrt{n}}{n} - 1}\right) \tag{which I can work out}
\end{align*}

But then I don't know what to do from there (or even if this is right).

I also tried an alternate approach using the alternate definition of convergence in distribution:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}\left[f\left(\log{\left((X_{1}\times\cdots\times X_{n})^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}e^{\sqrt{n}}\right)}\right)\right] = \mathbb{E}\left(f(X)\right)$$

but I also don't see how to proceed with this. I already know that $\mathbb{E}(\log(X_i)) = -1$, and that $\mathrm{Var}(\log(X_i)) = 2$, but I don't see how this helps.

Comment: In fact you've found the important pieces of information: $E[\log(X_i)]=-1$ and $\operatorname{Var}(\log(X_i))=2$, which means that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum \log(X_i) + \sqrt{n}$ has mean zero and variance $2$ for every $n$. Does this look familiar?

Comment: Look like Central Limit theorem: $\sqrt{n} \big(\frac{1}{n}\sum(Y_i) - \mu \big) \rightarrow N(0,\sigma^2)$ in distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the random variables are i.i.d. does not imply that $\sum_{i=1}^n\log X_i$ has the same distribution as $n\log X_1$.

However, since you proved that $\mathbb{E}\left[\log(X_i)\right] = -1$, we have 
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n\log\left(X_i\right) + \sqrt{n}
=\frac 1{\sqrt n}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\log\left(X_i\right)-
\mathbb E\left[\log\left(X_i\right)\right]\right).$$
Now, since the sequence $\left(\log\left(X_i\right)-
\mathbb E\left[\log\left(X_i\right)\right]\right)_{i\geqslant 1}$ is i.i.d. and has a finite variance, we can use the central limit theorem.